# 2-Dimensions Array - how to count the 2nd array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, count, size

I am looking for a code in xcode for getting the sum of the 2nd array.
You see my questions within the code. I am appreciate if anybode could support me in this way:

```
animation_images_buffer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *animationen_1 = @[@"image1_1.png", @" image1_2.png ", @" image1_3.png”]; 
NSArray *animationen_2 =  @[@"image2_1.png", @" image2_2.png ", @" image2_3.png ", @" image2_4.png ", @" image2_5.png”];

[animation_images_buffer addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: animationen_1]];    
[animation_images_buffer addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: animationen_2]];    

// I would like to get the sum of animationen_2
for (int i = 0; i < animationen_2.count; i++) { 
// …    
}

// Is it possible to do it like this anyhow?

for (int i = 0; i < animation_images_buffer[2].count;i++{
 // …
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the context of your question, I assume you don't mean "sum" (what is the sum of strings?) But the SIZE of the array (how many strings/elements there are)

Since there is no array_name.count like you are trying to do...

You want: [array_name count]

As in: NSLog(@"there are %d objects in the array",  [array count])

Comment: Thanks Tobiah for your comment, that is correct. I would like the size of an array. But for example:

Comment: Thanks Tobiah for your comment. Yes, I would like the size of the 2nd array. So in your code, I do not know the array_name, because I want the array dynamic. Do you know, if it is possible to get the Array_name from an array?  It should like this way:     NSString *name_of_arrayname_on_position_2 = animation_images_buffer[2], but when I would do this, I do not get the array_name like animationen_2, instead of this I get the content of the array for position 2 in the variable. Thanks in advance for any further comments. Sorry for wrong commenting, but I do have problems to write this message.

Comment: Array_name isnt a special field, i mean the variable name of the array Ex: animation_images_buffer or animationen_2. If you wanted the size of the third array in animation_images_buffer, you would do: [animation_images_buffer[2] count]